# getting unique records from table who has multiple occurences

Tags: sql

I trying to pull up all the patient records(without duplication). In my database all the patients have multiple visit ID's and multiple visit dates.

I have tried this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM PatientVisit
WHERE Visit IN (SELECT MIN(Visit) FROM  PatientVisit GROUP BY PatientProfileId)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  Sample data, desired results, and a proper database tag are helpful.

Comment: If you just want distinct patient data, just remove those columns from your select distinct statement. i.e. `select distinct patientid,firstname,lastname from patientvisit`. Examples are essential.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT VisitMain.PatientID
    ,MaxVisit.FirstVisit
    ,MinVisit.LastVisit
FROM
    PatientVisit VisitMain (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        PatientID,FirstVisit = MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME,Visit))
     FROM 
        PatientVisit (NOLOCK)
     GROUP BY
        PatientID) MaxVisit
ON VisitMain.PatientID = MaxVisit.PatientID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        PatientID,LastVisit = MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME,Visit))
     FROM 
        PatientVisit (NOLOCK)
     GROUP BY
        PatientID) MinVisit
ON VisitMain.PatientID = MinVisit.PatientID
```